# Uploading Click Once to app service results in this error:Application manifest has either a different computed hash than the one specified or no hash

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, vsto, clickonce

I made an MVC app that hosts a vsto click once installer. The setup.exe installs the app well when its in local host but when it's in a hosted app service the click once is producing an error with this message

"Application manifest has either a different computed hash than the one specified or no hash specified at all"

I don't think that it has a problem with manifest files as it's working correctly in local host.
This is currently how I let the click once access the files

```
public ActionResult vsto(string id,string id2,string id3)
        {

            string path = String.IsNullOrEmpty(id2)? @"~\vsto\" + id : @"~\vsto\" + id + @"\" + id2 + @"\" +id3;
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(path);
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
            string content = "application /octet-stream";
            if (String.Equals(extension, ".manifest"))
            {
                content = "application/x-ms-manifest";
            }
            else if (String.Equals(extension, ".application"))
            {
                content = "application/x-ms-application";
            }
            return File(path, content, fileName);
        }
```

and I also have this in my web config.

```
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".application" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".application" mimeType="application/x-ms-application" />
        <remove fileExtension=".manifest" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".manifest" mimeType="application/x-ms-manifest" />
        <remove fileExtension=".deploy" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".deploy" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <remove fileExtension=".msu" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".msu" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <remove fileExtension=".msp" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".msp" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
```

For anyone that would suggest to use a Storage Account.I had problems using storage account so I need to resort with this method.

Thanks.

Comment: I also tried resigning the .vsto and manifest file using mage but the issue still persists.